# Same messages in a topic are getting read by consumer group repeatedly

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, spring-kafka

I have created topic with 10 partitions and replication factor is 2.And I have created consumer group with some 'xyz' group name and concurrency set 10, so that 10 consumers can start consuming from 10 partitions parallelly i,e each partition can be consumed by each consumer but some how same messages are getting read by consumer group again and again, below my code, please let me know what I am doing wrong,

KafkaTopicConfig:

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaTopicConfig {

    @Value(value = "${kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapAddress;

    @Bean
    public KafkaAdmin kafkaAdmin() {
        Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>();
        configs.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        return new KafkaAdmin(configs);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return new NewTopic("someTopicName", 10, (short) 2);
    }
}
```

KafkaProducerConfig:

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfig {

    @Value(value = "${kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapAddress;

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, Event> producerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
        config.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        config.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        config.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(config);
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, Event> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }

}
```

KafkaConsumerConfig :

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

    @Value(value = "${kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapAddress;

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, Event> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "someGroupId");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "true");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "100");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "15000");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(config, new StringDeserializer(),
                new JsonDeserializer<>(Event.class));
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Event> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Event> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setConcurrency(10);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setPollTimeout(500);
        return factory;
    }
}
```

Listener:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "someTopicName", groupId = "someGroupId")
public void consume(Event event) {

    // business logic

}
```

Please let me know any other information needed and also let me know what I am doing wrong

Comment: You are not providing enough information - under what circumstances are you seeing the same records "over and over again". BTW, it's more reliable to set `enable.auto.commit` to `false` so the container commits the offsets as messages are processed.

Comment: @GaryRussell
In my case, I have a producer which is producing almost 15000 messages and multiple consumers(10 consumers) are parallely consuming the messages but at some point of time,after consuming approximately 2000 messages, the same messages are being consumed.

And also please let me know how to achieve container to commit the offsets, it would be good if you provide sample piece of code.

Comment: Just set the property to false; then the container will commit the offsets automatically after each batch of records received from the consumer `poll()` operationl the default `ackMode` property is `AckMode.BATCH`. You can also set the ackmode `AckMode.RECORD` and the offset will be committed after each record is processed. See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#committing-offsets). You still need to provide more information "the same records"? All 2000? Some of them? Have you looked in the logs to see if a partition rebalance occurred?

Comment: Perhaps you are taking too long to process each batch. Try reducing `max.poll.records`.

Comment: I am adding below piece of code in 'ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory' bean in KafkaConsumerConfig class, is that correct way to set AckMode.RECORD . Please confirm.


factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.AckMode.RECORD);

And also please let me know where can I set max.poll.records?

Comment: Yes; that is correct. `config.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS, 50)`.

Comment: @GaryRussell
Thank you very much.Let me try these changes and I will get back to you.

Comment: @GaryRussell
producing and consuming is happening but in the middle getting below exception many times, please let me know what changes I need to do

Comment: @GaryRussell

org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. You can address this either by increasing the session timeout or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.

Comment: @GaryRussell
Please let me know what changes I need to do

Comment: The error is quite clear. As I suggested, you are taking too long to process the results of the `poll()`. You need to reduce `max.poll.records` and/or increase `max.poll.interval.ms`.

Comment: @GaryRussell
Yeah actually I am not sure how much max.poll.records and max.poll.interval.ms do I need to give.It could be great if you suggest these numbers

Comment: It depends on how long it takes you to process one record - do the math and add some safety.

Comment: @GaryRussell
What about session timeout?

Comment: Read [KIP-62](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-62%3A+Allow+consumer+to+send+heartbeats+from+a+background+thread). Session timeout is less important now since heartbeats are sent in the background. (Assuming you are using a supported version of Spring-Kafka (1.3.x or higher).

Comment: @GaryRussell
I have one doubt, I am also setting PollTimeout =500, could you please tell me what is the difference between max.poll.interval.ms and PollTimeout. Please confirm in my case do I need to set both these value?

Comment: Poll timeout is how long we wait in the poll to get some records, if none arrive, we simply loop around and poll again; it has no impact on rebalancing. `max.poll.interval.ms` is the time between `poll()`s. If it is exceeded, Kafka thinks we're dead and rebalances the topics/partitions,. So, you MUST process all records returned by a poll in less than that time.

Comment: @GaryRussell
Ok got you. Let me try to set max.poll.records and max.poll.interval.ms with appropriate value and I will get back to you.

Comment: @GaryRussell
I am very sorry for late reply,I was stuck with some other issue.As you suggested I have tried changing max.poll.records, max.poll.interval.ms and also session.timeout.ms it worked for me :)
Thank you very much :)